# EF: how work EntityState tracking for not "virtual" propertys

Tags: .net, entity-framework

how is track EntityState for propertys that are not marked as `virtual`?

here example:

```
var person = db.Persons.First();
person.Name = "bla bla";
Console.WriteLine(db.Entry(person).State);  //Output: Modified. How he know??
```

Class structure:

```
class Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because ***Automatic Change*** tracking is enabled by default.

```
public YourDbContext
{
  Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
}
```

By default, Entity Framework creates a snaphot for all entities when they are loaded from Database. When you need to save these entities to the database, it compares this snapshot of all entities to their current state, and then it updates the database based on the state of these entities.If you modify any property of an entity that you loaded from DB, and call after that the `db.Entry` method or `db.SaveChanges` method, internally it will call first the [DetectChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker.detectchanges(v=vs.113).aspx) method to detects changes that were made to the properties and relationships in that entity. If it detect some change, then it will change the State to `Modified`.

The easiest way to get access to the change tracking information for an entity is using the `Entry` method on DbContext. `Entry` returns a `DbEntityEntry` instance, which gives you access to the information and operations available for the entity.Once you get it, you can access `OriginalValues` and `CurrentValues` properties. Both of them are of type `DbPropertyValues`.

Comment: thank, i understand. the point of the answer for me its: _Entity Framework creates a snaphot for all entities when they are loaded from Database._